# pieSeries "tips" has incomplete background in Customer Portal (see screenshot)

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal

In my Customer Portal, the [pie chart](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pieSeries.htm) shows incomplete **background (rectangle)** on hover tips over the wedges. I can make `tips="false"` to not show the hover tips, but I need the hover tips. How do I make the rectangular background span the whole content of the tips?

[image]

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
    <apex:chart data="{!Summaries}" height="200" width="200">
        <apex:pieSeries labelField="careerLatticeLevel"
            dataField="recordCount" donut="50" showInLegend="true" />
    </apex:chart>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an [apex:chartTips](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chartTips.htm) element with your desired width/height. This gives you a lot of customizability including a JS callback that overrides the default rendering function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `auto` keyword does not work here. The value needs to be a number. Do you know if there is a way to make the width/height as `auto`?

Comment: Probably not supported, sadly, sort of like you (STILL) can't specify a height or width in a VisualForce component on a standard page layout. I'm fairly certain you could override the behavior via some hack-ish JavaScript but it would be a bit of work. If you want help with that, you'll need to post the rendered HTML that you're getting from your chart (a JSFiddle would be ideal) and exactly what you're trying to do.